# Setting the height of a table in HTML has no effect

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why does this table height not function?

```
<table border=1 bgcolor="green" width=80% height="30%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" >
            This is 1st row 1st column
        </td>
        <td >
            2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQNS4/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just add the following to your css:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

As other said, a `table` doesn't have a `height`-attriute, but most browsers intrepet that anyway. you can see [the result on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQNS4/1/).

The reason you need to do this is that the parent element of anything that should have a height in % must have a height too (as Shadow Wizard said: "30% of what exactly?" - the parent has to have a height).

Answer (score 0):

The `table` tag does not contain a `height` attribute.  Try setting the height of the table using CSS styling.

```
table{
   height: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <table border=1 bgcolor="green">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" >
                This is 1st row 1st column
            </td>
            <td>
                 2
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The code sample is good, but how does your code solve the question? Why did the original code not work?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.
I have table inside a container ( div `config-table` ), just setting `height` didn't work for me. I had to set `overflow: auto` ( for my case `auto` was needed ) and now work

```
.config-table {
   height: 350px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```