# How to set table height on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `HTML` table tag as following

```
<table class="globaltable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" height="72%" onclick="alert(this.offsetHeight)">
```

where in `IE8` i have onclick value as 420, in `chrome` as 480 and in `firefox` as 472. How do i make it uniform across different browsers.

Comment: min-width does not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the height of a table in HTML has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809502/setting-the-height-of-a-table-in-html-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your setting the table to 72% of what???

you need to add the folling to your html,body css file

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

this will allow the tables to be the same across all the browsers as you have then set the parent hight

Answer (score 1):

Mention height in `style` attribute. If you use height in `px` it is common in all browsers. If you use `%` it varies based on browser computability.

```
<table class="globaltable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  width="100%"
 style="height: 720px;" align="center" onclick="alert(this.offsetHeight)">  
<tr>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Height` parameter is based on the browser toolbars and tools which they increase or decrease the space. You are using 72 present of visible space. For example if you Restore your window and increase the height of you page, you will see different size in any browser.
So, what should we do?
I recommend you to use height of page with pixel based size like this:
instead of

```
html, body { height :100%; }
```

use

```
html, body { height :300px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`globaltable` is inside another tag. That tag has a `height`. Your rule states that `globaltable` will have a `height` which is `72%` of its parent. So you need to make sure that the parent of `globaltable` has a fixed `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser is different, so that the offset window. Browser toolbars are the have different sizes and this affects the size of your window. If you want to produce "responsive design" uses percentages as you do. If you want the window does not change the size of your element, instead use a fixed size.

Be careful, Mozilla does not support `height:100%`. You rather use JavaScript and this kind of function:

```
resizeFn = function(){
    document.querySelector( ".globaltable" )
        .style.height = ( window.offsetHeight * 42 / 100 );
};

window.addEventListener && addEventListener( "resize", resizeFn ) && addEventListener( "load", resizeFn ) || 
window.attachEvent && attachEvent( "resize", resizeFn ) && attachEvent( "load", resizeFn );
```