# How to make this div with display:table take the height of 80% of its parent, without affecting the negative margins of table-cells

Tags: html, css, height, css-tables

**[JSFiddle here!](https://jsfiddle.net/k47ehry8/)**

In this SSCCE, I have given a `display:table` property to `.container`, which contains `<section>` elements with `display:table-row` property, and each `section` has an `<img>` with `display:table-cell` property, and another nested `<section>` with `display:table-cell` property.

In the first column, each table-cell contains an image, and because I have used negative margin-bottom on the table-cells in this column, all the images in the first column give the look/illusion of one image.

**What I want is that the `.container` `div` (with `display:table;`) should get a `height` of the "height of the viewport** (that is the visible-screen-size without scrolling) **MINUS a `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` of `200px` each." So that the *illusion-of-the-image* in the first column shrinks to that size.**

```css
 @import url(<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300,600,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>);
 .section-big {
   padding: 100px 0;
 }
 .section-big .container {
   width: 970px;
   margin: 200px auto;
 }
 .section-big .col {
   width: 47%;
 }
 .section-big .col-left {
   float: left;
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 25px;
 }
 .section-big .col-right {
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: 25px;
 }
 .section-big .col-left img {
   height: 80%;
   width: 50%;
 }
 h3 {
   color: #6c6969;
   transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 40px;
 }
 h5 {
   color: #6c6969;
   transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 .container {
   display: table;
   margin: 200px auto;
 }
 .container>section {
   display: table-row;
 }
 .col1td,
 .col2td {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding: 0px 25px;
   /*height: 250px;*/
 }
 .top1 {
   vertical-align: bottom;
   margin-bottom: -64px;
 }
 .top2 {
   vertical-align: top;
   margin-bottom: -62px;
   /*margin-left:45px;*/
 }
 .top3 {
   vertical-align: top;
   margin-bottom: -62px;
   /*margin-left:45px;*/
 }
 .top5 {
   vertical-align: top;
   margin-bottom: -62px;
   /*margin-left:25px;*/
 }
 .section-big {
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="section-big">
  <div class="container">


    <section class="section-one">
      <img class="col1td top1" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0a97/utelxs08krq3fd3zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 1">
      <section class="col2td">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
    </section>


    <section class="section-two">
      <img class="col1td top2" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7f55/jsl7mw25qbs3e54zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 2">
      <section class="col2td">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
    </section>


    <section class="section-three">
      <img class="col1td top3" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6e7e/jjd597oeexkd5h4zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 3">
      <section class="col2td">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
    </section>


    <section class="section-four">
      <img class="col1td top5" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d99d/4g75pbwt1c59971zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 5">
      <section class="col2td">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
    </section>


  </div>
</div>
```

***WHAT I TRIED:***

1. I saw [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_width), and tried to give a `height:500px;` as well
   as `height:50%;` after giving the `body` a `height:100%;`, but that
   does not seem to have any effect.
2. I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809502/setting-the-height-of-a-table-in-html-has-no-effect) and gave the `.section-big` a
   `height:100vh` so that if I give the `.container` (the
   `display:table` element) a percentage `height` (which will be
   calculated as X% of the height of `.section-big`). So I gave `.container` a `height:80%;` and adjusted the `margin-bottom`s of table-cells of first column, which resulted in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k47ehry8/4/). **BUT**

   - first, the `section-big` does get a `height:100vh` as I can see that
     by
        hovering over it in the Google chrome inspector, but that 100vh is
        overflowing below the visible viewport as shown in the following
        figure.
   - Second, even the `body` does not start at the top of the document as
     shown in the following screenshot.

     [image]
   - Third, the `.container` bleeds/overflows out of its parent
     `section-big`.

     [image]

   JSFiddle here. So I am clueless about what to do!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.. it could help...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heading-bar">
        <u>
            <li><a class="js-scroll" href="#section-one">section1</a></li>
            <li><a class="js-scroll" href="#section-two">section2</a></li>
            <li><a class="js-scroll" href="#section-three">section3</a></li>
            <li><a class="js-scroll" href="#section-four">section4</a></li>
        </u>
        <header>
            <h1>heading</h1>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <section id="section-one">
            <img class="col1td top1" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0a97/utelxs08krq3fd3zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 1">
            <section class="col2td">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
        </section>

        <section id="section-two">
            <img class="col1td top2" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7f55/jsl7mw25qbs3e54zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 2">
            <section class="col2td">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
        </section>

        <section id="section-three">
            <img class="col1td top3" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6e7e/jjd597oeexkd5h4zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 3">
            <section class="col2td">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
        </section>

        <section id="section-four">
             <img class="col1td top5" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d99d/4g75pbwt1c59971zg.jpg" alt="ton ton 5">
            <section class="col2td">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
```

css

```
 /*@import url(<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300,600,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>);*/
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
    }
         .heading-bar {
            height: 200px;
            background-color: white;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
         }
         li {
            direction: ltr;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 10px;
            display: inline-block;

         }
         li a{

         }
    .container {
           width: 80%;       
           overflow: scroll;


         }
         .section-big .col {
           width: 47%;
         }
         .section-big .col-left {
           float: left;
           text-align: right;
           padding-right: 25px;
         }
         .section-big .col-right {
           float: left;
           text-align: left;
           padding-left: 25px;
         }
         .section-big .col-left img {
           height: 80%;
           width: 50%;
         }
         h3 {
           color: #6c6969;
           transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
           font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
           font-weight: 600;
           font-size: 40px;
         }
         h5 {
           color: #6c6969;
           transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
           font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
           font-weight: 400;
           font-size: 20px;
         }
         .container {
           display: table;
           margin: 200px auto;
         }
         .container>section {
           display: table-row;
         }
         .col1td,
         .col2td {
           display: table-cell;
           vertical-align: middle;
           padding: 0px 25px;
           /*height: 250px;*/
         }
         .top1 {
           vertical-align: bottom;
           margin-bottom: -64px;
         }
         .top2 {
           vertical-align: top;
           margin-bottom: -62px;
           /*margin-left:45px;*/
         }
         .top3 {
           vertical-align: top;
           margin-bottom: -62px;
           /*margin-left:45px;*/
         }
         .top5 {
           vertical-align: top;
           margin-bottom: -62px;
           /*margin-left:25px;*/
         }
         .section-big {
           height: 100vh;
           padding: 0px;
           margin: 0px;
         }
```

javascript

```
    $('.js-scroll').click(function(){

        var headerHeight = 200;

        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - headerHeight
        }, 500);

        return false;
    });
```