# Wrong rendering while generating pdf from html in Java

Tags: java, flying-saucer

I'm trying to convert simple html to pdf but the styling in my browser is different than the one in pdf. I'm using flying-saucer-pdf v9.1.18. Do you have any idea why?

here is how it looks on web browser and how it looks in the generated pdf:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB7DB.jpg

Here is my simple html template:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .aligned {
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }
        
        .colored {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1" width="300px" height="300px">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td class="colored">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td class="aligned">6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

> No support for legacy or "street" HTML, although there are several
>   open source Java HTML cleaners of varying quality available. We render
>   well-formed XML; XHTML is a well-formed XML document which uses a
>   special set of tags. We can't render most HTML "in the wild". At best,
>   you can "clean up" old HTML with TagSoup or JTidy or similar library
>   and hope for the best. But without a bunch of work, you won't be able
>   to use Flying Saucer for a real web browser component. However, note
>   that's not a technical limitation, just a lack of time and resources.

The "height" attribute of TABLE tag is standard at all, I guess flying-saucer is ignoring it.

See e.g. [Setting the height of a table in HTML has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809502)